# Is it possible to prevent default onDeselect, (select input multiple ant design)?

Tags: reactjs, antd

What I´m trying to do is to control the onDeselect event, I want to ask a question before the event finish. And then if the user accept delete the option could be deleted.

This is my select and the props:

```
<Select
       mode="multiple"
       style={{ width: '100%' }}
       placeholder="Select at least one"
       allowClear={false}
       onSelect={this.addNewClassroom}
       onDeselect={this.deleteClasroom}
      >
        {classroomSelect}
</Select>
```

This is the function that I use:

```
deleteClasroom(val, e){

    //e.preventDefault();

    confirm({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      content: 'Delete this...',
      onOk() {
        //  -----------> delete the item 
      },
      onCancel() {
        //  -----------> keep the item 
       },
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onDeselect` happens after the event and does not expose such a functionality. However you can convert the component into a controlled component and implement your use case.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      values: ['a10', 'c12'],
    };
  }

  onDeselect = (value) => {
    const that = this;
    confirm({
      title: 'Are you sure delete this task?',
      content: 'Some descriptions',
      okText: 'Yes',
      okType: 'danger',
      cancelText: 'No',
      onOk() {
        that.setState(prevState => ({
          values: prevState.values.filter(item => item !== value),
        }));
      },
      onCancel() {
        ;
      },
    });
  }

  onSelect = (value) => {
    console.log(value)
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      values: [...prevState.values, value],
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          mode="multiple"
          style={{ width: '100%' }}
          placeholder="Please select"
          value={this.state.values}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
          onDeselect={this.onDeselect}
        >
          {children}
        </Select>,
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[See working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b4v6uw).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I was using getFieldDecorator I forgot that select is inside a form, this affects the script, I had to remove getFieldDecorator and it and works fine.